# gradle build successful but no dependencies were downloaded

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13'
    compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.4.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-orm:4.2.4.RELEASE"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and when i run "gradle eclipse"
it just says "Task 'eclipse' not found in root project 'WebPrimary'"

anyone can help? thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the:

```
apply plugin 'eclipse'
```

See: 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html